# Efficient traversal of a directed acyclic graph

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph, traversal

**Input:**

```
nd[0];
nd[1, 2];
nd[3, 4];
nd[0, 1];
nd[2, 3];
nd[0, 4];
nd[1, 3];
nd[0, 2];
nd[1, 4];
nd[3];
nd[1, 4];
```

**Resulting Tree:**

[image: Resulting tree from above code]

**Output:**

```
total_time = sum of all individual wait_time //without overlap
```

**Rules:**

- Input code will always result a directed acyclic graph
- Each node has some *wait_time* value
- A complete graph traversal should calculate the total *wait_time* of whole graph
- All independent nodes must be traversed in parallel (or at least time calculation should be in this way)
- If overlapping of *wait_time* of two different nodes occur then maximum value will be considered and traversal of a node with lesser time will move to the next independent node
- All single and paired nodes will have exactly 1 and 2 in-coming and out-going edges except roots and leaves (there can be multiple roots and leaves)

**Problem 1:** How to convert given input-code into the graph so it can be traversed? (pseudo-code or any kind of guidance might help)

**Problem 2:** How to achieve the successful traversal based on mentioned rules?

**Previous Effort:**

- I was able to sort the nodes in a linear way using *Topological
  sort*, but I am not sure how can I achieve these specific goals.
- I drew this graph based on my intuition from code.
- Digits on the edges are just to clarify what number is causing the
  dependency.
- I am using python 3
- My previous code does not seem to make any sense in relevance to
  these problems so I did not include that.

Comment: How is the input format specified? Why does the graph have an edge from 0 to (0,1), but no edge from 0 to (0,4) for example? How are the "wait times" determined; are they part of the input, or should they be derived somehow?

Comment: @kaya3 a linear approach will be followed for all dependent nodes, from the input-code it can be seen that (0,4) can only be visited after (0, 1) so it is not directly connected to 0. That is why (0,1) has the direct edge from 0.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain in words why you think that data should lead to that graph, then your problem #1 might have a solution.  As it stands I have no idea why you think that graph should be output.  Secondly I don't see the wait times anywhere.

Comment: @btilly It is like a dependency graph. It becomes necessary if we want to achieve parallelism (imo). The program will convert those single lines from input file into a graph as nodes, these nodes might have some data members including wait-time. Just for an example you can consider the wait-time is equal to the sum of digits mentioned on a single node. (that sum will be stored in a variable)

Comment: I don't understand what nd[x, y] means. Why is there an edge from [0] to [0,1] ? Why is there an edge from [1,2] to [0,1]?

Comment: @grodzi the input code is to show the dependency. For understanding think all digits as some registers [0-4]. Only one node can access a register at a time and priority is decided on the basis of their order in input-code. Edges represent the dependency. In above example: nd[1, 2] and nd[3, 4] can be traversed before/parallel to nd[0] because their registers aren't common however, nd[0, 1] cannot be traversed before nd[0] because here register(0) is common (that's causing the dependency - also mentioned on edges) and nd[0] comes earlier in input-code.

Comment: ok. It is clear @muruDiaz. Now two hopefully last questions:
I don't understand ```If overlapping of wait_time of two different nodes occur then maximum value will be considered and traversal of a node with lesser time will move to the next independent node```. Could you illustrate when that problem arise? Also, in the case of [0,1] which depends on [0] and [1,2]. When does [0,1] start? (when one of [0] or [1,2] is done or only when __both__ are done)

Comment: @grodzi **q1**: simply it means that time of traversal of all nodes that can be traversed in parallel will not be counted multiple times (I'm not sure about exact term but hope you got the idea?) eg: nd[0,4] and nd[1,3] takes 2 and 3 secs respectively but they can be traversed in parallel so here total time taken at this step will be 3s not 5s. **q2**: a dependent node cannot be traversed as long as it is dependent. That means all previous nodes nodes need to be traversed first. So, [0,1] will be done only after both [0] and [1,2] are done where [0] and [1,2] are irrelevant for each other.

Answer (score 0):

1. Creating the graph

Let `a, b, c` three nodes which have a `0` property/depandancy in common (to node 0). If `a` is discovered before `b`, and `b` discovered before `c`, edge should be `a->b` and `b->c`.

To address above rule, consider a cache for every discovered digit.
If a node includes `0`, then you cache it as `cache[0]`.
Later on if an other node `b` includes `0`, you must make an edge from `cache[0]` to `b`, and update that cache so that subsequent node including `0` get an edge from `b`.

```
foreach input as node
  forall dependancy of node
    if discovered[dependancy]
      make_edge(discovered[dependancy], node)
    fi
    discovered[dependancy] = node // apply dependancy "transitivity"
```

Now to build the graph as "layers" you can start from the leaves (layer `0`), here `[1,4],[0,2],[0,3]` only.
Then take the nodes whose output edge link to any of the leaves, here only `[1,4]`. (because `[1,3]` while linking to `[3]` which is a leaf, also links to `[1,4]` which is not. So excluded). You then have built the layer `1`.

> While building layer n, you can only add nodes having deps to layer 0 to n-1

A more compact way of saying this is for a node, to compute its eccentricity (the longest path (here to the leaves)).

To print the graph as you did, notice you can just plot the nodes by eccentricity which would show the "level" of dependancy (how far they are from the leaves/end, see `plotByLayers` in code below).

2. Computing the total time

We don't need to go to the hassle of building layers as above.

> A node can start only when all of its ancestors end.

The ancestors have already been determined when we made the graph.

The recursion is thus

```
n.endAt = max(n.endAt for n in n.ancestors) + n.wait
```

Initialization being for the root nodes (which have no dependancy) and where we can just keep the wait time.

```
nroot.endAt = nroot.wait
```

---

Regarding the node.id notation `i)x,y`. i is the ith node as read in input. (its *true* id somehow. `x,y` is just garbage to help us visualize).

```js
const input = `
nd[0];
nd[1, 2];
nd[3, 4];
nd[0, 1];
nd[2, 3];
nd[0, 4];
nd[1, 3];
nd[0, 2];
nd[1, 4];
nd[3];
nd[1, 4];`
function makeGraph(input) {
  const nodes = input.trim().split('\n').map((x,i) => {
    const deps = x.match(/\[(.+)\]/)[1]
    return { id: i+')'+deps, v: deps.split(',').map(x => x.trim()) }
  })
  const edges = {}
  const discovered = {}
  nodes.forEach((node, i) => {
    node.v.forEach(digit => {
      if (discovered[digit]) {
        // there is an edge
        edges[discovered[digit].id] = edges[discovered[digit].id] || []
        edges[discovered[digit].id].push(node)
      }
      // apply transitivity a->b->c
      discovered[digit] = node
    })
  }) 
  return {nodes, edges}
}

function computeEccentricity(n, edges) {
  if (typeof(n.eccentricity) !== 'undefined') {
    return n.eccentricity
  }
  if (!edges[n.id]) {// a leaf has no outgoing edges
    n.eccentricity = 0
    return 0
  }
  const distances = Object.values(edges[n.id]).map(n => computeEccentricity(n, edges))
  const min = Math.max(...distances)
  n.eccentricity = 1 + min
  return n.eccentricity
}

function plotByLayers(nodes) {
  const lvls = []
  let m = 0;
  nodes.forEach(n => {
    const i = n.eccentricity
    lvls[i] = lvls[i] || []
    lvls[i].push(n)
    m = i > m ? i: m
  })
  for(let i = m; i >=0 ; --i) {
    console.log(lvls[i].map(x => x.id))
  }
  return lvls
}
const { nodes, edges } = makeGraph(input)
nodes.forEach(n => computeEccentricity(n, edges))
plotByLayers(nodes)

// for any node, compute its ancestors.
nodes.forEach((n, i) => {
  if (edges[n.id]) {
    edges[n.id].forEach(v => {
      v.ancestors = v.ancestors || []
      v.ancestors.push(n)
    })
  }
  n.wait = 2**i // say arbitrarily that i node waits 2^i some time
})
function computeEndAt(node) {
  if (typeof(node.endAt) !== 'undefined') {
    return node.endAt
  }
  if (!node.ancestors) {
    node.endAt = 0 + node.wait
    return node.endAt
  }
  const maxEnd = Math.max(...node.ancestors.map(computeEndAt))
  node.endAt = maxEnd + node.wait
  return node.endAt
}
nodes.forEach(computeEndAt)
const longest = nodes.sort((a,b)=>b.endAt - a.endAt)[0]
console.log('awaited: ', longest.endAt, longest.id)
```